# Open whole application in SDK from push notifications

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a SDK for use in android application and I want to control push notifications on my side for the hosted application that integrate my SDK.
Pushes are coming currently OK and everything is fine except for one thing:

When a push arrives I open a certain Activity based on what comes from the Server and the scenario is that I see my new Activity opens OK but it opens only it, it doesn't open the hosted application as a "whole".
Which I understand that this is the behaviour in iOS.

What it means is that when I close the Activity there is no option to go back to the hosted activity at all (Which I presume is the default behaviour when open single activity from push notifications).

So my question is this:

Can I open the hosted application from a push just like when user opens it from home screen and show the pending activity that is opens from push on top of that ? So when user closes it he returns to the Application initial state ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options the first is bad and the second is the correct one

1- Pass something to the intent of the application's main activity that you can check and open the desired activity without finishing the main one. This is bad because it'll be so heavy to load because it opens two activities instead of one

2- Open the desired activity and override the Activity's `onBackPressed()` to check if the activity is on top of the application stack then open the main activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isTaskRoot()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

what isTaskRoot() do?

> public boolean **isTaskRoot()**
>
> Added in **API level 1**
>
> Return whether this activity is the root of a task. The root is the
>   first activity in a task.

Comment: I'm unaware of the code of the hosting app. that's why I'm trying to see if there is a way to do it without touching the hosting application's code.